# Unity3D: WebGL size - 25mb js - am I doing anything wrong?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I am testing different technologies around, choosing the next platform I'd like to create my next simple game with, now it's Unity's turn.

The ability to export to WebGL is a paramount for me. I created a simple test game in Unity, exported it to WebGL and got... 25MB js file and 10MB data file! Looks like I am doing something wrong, perhaps, there is some sort of "dead code elimination" configuration check box I didn't check.. isn't there? I hope there is...

Comment: What have you tried? Searching the web for "unity reduce webgl size" returns plenty of options.

Comment: @CodeCaster, yes, I did search for it, all I see is a discussion about how to zip it with mod_deflate. And result in only 10MB instead of 35MB, great! But not for me. 10MB, even 5MB is too huge a boilerplate for a couple of spinning cubes on my scene, isn't it?

Comment: You say test game. What do you mean by that?

Comment: WebGL is just an experimental technology.  As of writing, you can use it for nothing.  Why waste your time with this?

Comment: @Kokolo, what I mean by that is a simple test with a couple of rotating boxes, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if you leave Development build in your build settings it includes a lot of unnecessary things in. 
@Joe Blow - what do you mean you can use it for nothing? it's getting better all the time.